# Numpy: load multiple CSV files as dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy, dictionary

I wanted to use the [numpy loadtxt method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to read `.csv` files for my experiment. I have three different time-series data of the following format with different characteristics where the first column is timestamp and the second column is the value.

```
0.086206438,10
0.086425551,12
0.089227066,20
0.089262508,24
0.089744425,30
0.090036815,40
0.090054172,28
0.090377569,28
0.090514071,28
0.090762872,28
0.090912691,27
```

For reproducibility, I have shared the three time-series data I am using [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CoTiB3Tg_722OTc7Hum3hYOB3LLpfg7c).

If I do it like the following

```
import numpy as np

fname="data1.csv"

col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(fname,delimiter=',').T
```

It works fine as intended. However instead of reading only a single file, I want to pass a dictionary to `col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(types,delimiter=',').T` as the following

`protocols = {}
types = {"data1": "data1.csv", "data2": "data2.csv", "data3": "data3.csv"}`

so that I can read multiple `csv` files and do plot all the results at ones using a one `for loop` as in the following.

```
for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time, col_window = protocols[protname]["col_time"], protocols[protname]["col_window"]
    rt = np.exp(np.diff(np.log(col_window)))
    plt.plot(quotient_times, quotient, ".", markersize=4, label=protname)
    plt.title(protname)
    plt.xlabel("t")
    plt.ylabel("values")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

But it is giving me an error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'data1'`. How can I load multiple `csv` files as a dictionary?

Comment: `loadtxt` only works with one file.  You have to load each one and join the data appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to build a `protocols` dict that will be useable in your code, you can easily build it with a simple loop:

```
types = {"data1": "data1.csv", "data2": "data2.csv", "data3": "data3.csv"}
protocols = {}

for name, file in types.items():
    col_time, col_window = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter=',').T
    protocols[name] = {'col_time': col_time, 'col_window': col_window}
```

You can then successfully plot the 3 graphs:

```
for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time, col_window = protocols[protname]["col_time"], protocols[protname]["col_window"]
    rt = np.exp(np.diff(np.log(col_window)))
    plt.plot(col_time, col_window, ".", markersize=4, label=protname)
    plt.title(protname)
    plt.xlabel("t")
    plt.ylabel("values")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: @Brown: at the end of the loop, a variable keeps the last value it has received inside the loop. But when running the loop, it receives all the expected values. With your example data I could display 3 different graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Loading data from multiple CSV files is not supported in pandas and numpy. You can use `concat` function of pandas `DataFrame` and load all the files. The example bellow demonstrates using pandas. Replace `StringIO` with file object.

```
data="""
0.086206438,10
0.086425551,12
0.089227066,20
0.089262508,24
0.089744425,30
0.090036815,40
0.090054172,28
0.090377569,28
0.090514071,28
0.090762872,28
0.090912691,27
"""
data2="""
0.086206438,29
0.086425551,32
0.089227066,50
0.089262508,54
"""
data3="""
0.086206438,69
0.086425551,72
0.089227066,70
0.089262508,74
"""
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
files={"data1":data,"data2":data2,"data3":data3}
# Load the first file into data frame
key=list(files.keys())[0]
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(files.get(key)),header=None,usecols=[0,1],names=['data1','data2'])
print(df.head())
# remove file from dictionary
files.pop(key,None)
print("final values")
# Efficient :Concat this dataframe with remaining files
df=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(StringIO(files[i]),header=None,usecols=[0,1],names=['data1','data2']) for i in files.keys()],
           ignore_index=True)
print(df.tail())
```

For more insight: [pandas append vs concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)